# custom page templating in WordPress

Tags: pages, page-template

I'm in a situation where I need to face a situation when there is a WordPress site with landing page and several internal page designs. I know for such situations there is recommended to create more template files for pages with some comments at the beginning like `Template Name: Some Style`

I've done this already, but the problem is that many of the internal pages contains boxes, areas that are independent from the main template. Let me show you:

[image]

So let's suppose we have the main article area and two other boxes. All the three areas have different design. First with some nice background, the bottom left article in a box with background and gradient stuff, the bottom right article is a box also with background and gradient with title and content inside.

I was asked to solve the situation in a manner when the site admin (who don't know any piece of coding) wants to add another similar article with same structure, to be able to do this.

Should I create one single template for this or three? What do you suggest? The idea when new article/page is added, to contain only the usual WordPress generated codes like h2, p, i, etc. So no manually added div's, classes and similar stuff.

Did you faced similar situation? I searched the internet and did not found anything yet. I was thinking something about shortcodes but that will involde tu use codes like `[some]content...[/some]` or even to have children pages, but nothing is clear for me yet. What do you suggest for me?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you'd need to add shortcodes to the functions.php file in your themes folder in order to use code like [box]Contained content blah blah[/box] in the WYSIWYG editor learn more about shortcodes and how to use them here http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: The question is if there is any other way which not include codes?

Comment: Not unless you add the HTML into the WYSIWYG.

Comment: HTML it is NOT accepted in this situation.

Comment: You could use a plugin called page.ly MultiEdit...

Comment: this suggestion deserves an acceptance :) thank you very much! this is far the best solution i've ever seen. there is also the "Secondary HTML Content" plugin... but your suggestion is better :)